# restrict a textfield in table view from entering

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building an app which contains user details view. i have used table view to keep 3 textfield. what i want to do is, when user clicks edit button, 1st textfield(phone Number TF) should not allow user to enter data & in remaining 2 textfield should allow user enter data. thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your cell For row at indexopath ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"XXXXX"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];

    }

 cell.yourTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
if (indexPath.row == 0) // it disable your interaction in first cell
{
 cell.yourTextfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
 }

return cell;
}
```

**Choice-2**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"XXXXX"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];

    }

 cell.yourTextfield.tag = indexPath.row; // set tag for each textfield


return cell;
}
```

> on that delegate fire disable the interaction

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
BOOL editable;
if (textField.tag == 0) {
    editable = NO;
} else if (textField.tag == 1 || textField.tag == 2) {
    editable = YES;
}
return editable;
}
```

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik. - yes, its working fine..since im using dynamic tableview cell, i did like this: if ([titlle isEqualToString:kPhoneNo]) {
        profilecell.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        profilecell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

Comment: @SanjayBharadwaj - happy to hear bro, de well , congrats and accept the answer it is useful in future

Answer (score 3):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` **property**:

```
//UITextField *textfield;
textfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // TO stop UserInteraction and Yes TO enable User Interaction
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a table view to present three textfields. Basically, tableview's used for present big amount of data.

But you could simply set **userInteractionEnabled** to *NO* to prevent changing textfield.

Otherwise, if you still want to use tableview you still can disable user interaction in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`